# jQuery gallery with filters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have developed a bespoke gallery within jQuery, which works how I want, so you can click the previous and next button to change the images, however I am wanting something additional.

I currently have a gallery that has filters on. The filters work by adding a "style="display: none;" to the elements when the are not part of that specific filter.

Now, using the code that currently works, it breaks when it comes across those elements, as it has a display none associated to it.

I basically need to ignore all of the elements that have a "display: none" on and go next and previous to the next one visible.

This is how my code looks:

```
<li class="mix autumn food " data-myorder="1">
<a href="#">
<div class="image" style="background-image: url(URL GOES HERE); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
</div><!--image-->
<div class="gallery_overlay"><span></span><h6>View large image</h6></div><!--gallery_overlay-->
</a>
<div class="image_large">
<span class="gallery_close"></span>
<span class="prev">PREV</span>
<span class="next">NEXT</span>
<div class="image_wrap" style="background-image: url(URL GOES HERE); background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div><!--image_wrap-->
</div><!--image_large-->
</li>
```

So it adds the "display: none" to the class of mix.

Please see below my jQuery that works with the previous and next:

```
$('#gallery_list ul li .image_large span.next').click(function(){
    $('#gallery_list ul li .image_large').hide();
    $(this).parent().parent().next().find('.image_large').show();
});

$('#gallery_list ul li .image_large span.prev').click(function(){
    $('#gallery_list ul li .image_large').hide();
    $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('.image_large').show();
});
```

Any help on this would be massively appreciated.

Many thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this. Find the first visible

```
$('#gallery_list ul li .image_large span.next').click(function(){
    $('#gallery_list ul li .image_large').hide();
    $(this).parent().parent().nextAll("li:visible:first").find('.image_large').show();
});

$('#gallery_list ul li .image_large span.prev').click(function(){
    $('#gallery_list ul li .image_large').hide();
    $(this).parent().parent().prevAll("li:visible:first").find('.image_large').show();
});
```